# How to return entries that have more than one entry per column

Tags: sql, mysql

Let's say I have a table like this:

| Client | Address |
| --- | --- |
| John | Address 1 |
| Joel | Address 1, Address 2 |
| Sarah | Address 3, Address 4 |

And I want to return a table like this:

| Client | Address |
| --- | --- |
| Joel | Address 1, Address 2 |
| Sarah | Address 3, Address 4 |

How would I do that?

I don't know which statements to use

Comment: `SELECT ... WHERE ...`?

Comment: It depends on what's the criteria you're using. There are dozens of criteria that can be used to achieve that output from your input, and they're all different and would behave differently in slightly different data environments.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing you always want to do when deciding how to filter on data is find an identifying factor that you can leverage to create said filter.

For your example data, an identifying factor is the comma that only exists in entries with two addresses.  So a filter that would work on your example data is:

```
WHERE Address LIKE '%,%'
```